# Warning: require_once(../core/Config.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

I have a question about require_once in php.

First this my folder structure:

- monsite.dev

  - classes

    - Database.inc
    - Users.inc
    - UsersProfile.inc
  - core

    - Config.inc
  - web

    - Index.php
  - tester.php

`Database.inc` to connect to my database

`web/Index.php` for home page

`tester.php` just for testing thing

I use `require_once` to link file together, which works almost very good except for the `tester.php`, which keeps telling me "failed to open the stream".

I tried 2 different way in `tester.php`:

1 - `require_once '../classes/database.inc';` (failed to open Database.inc)

2 - `require_once 'Users/Nicks/Sites/monsite/classes/database.inc';`(failed to open Config.inc)

But when I use it from `index.php` (require_once ../classes/database.inc) it works perfectly.

Why is this not working from `tester.php` while it works from `index.php`?

Many thanks for any help.

Nic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because that is the incorrect path. In `tester.php` it should be:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/classes/Database.inc";
```

Using `../` goes back up a level. Therefore in your directory structure, you're saying that the `classes/` directory is alongside the `monsite.dev` directory. Not inside it.

When used in `index.php`, which is in a subdirectory, you have to go back up a level - which is why it works from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once 'classes/Database.inc';
```

You can use this because file is on same directory.

Answer (score 0):

`tester.php` & `classes` directory is on same folder so no need of `../`. Try with -

```
require_once 'classes/Database.inc';
```